# Use of glue in map in an RMarkdown in a new environment

Tags: r, r-markdown, purrr, environment, r-glue

Consider the following `Rmarkdown` document:

````
---
title: "Environments"
author: "Me"
date: "2023-01-13"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup}
library(glue)
library(purrr)
```

```{r vars}
a <- 1
x <- list("`a` has the value: {a}")
```

```{r works}
glue(x[[1L]])
```

```{r does-not-work, error = TRUE}
map_chr(x, glue)
```
````

When using `RStudio's` *knit* button, everything works like a charm and the output is as follows:

[image: The rendered HTML file where all chunks are rendered properly]

However, if I try to call render myself with an **own** environment, it fails:

```r
ne <- new.env()
render("env.Rmd", envir = ne)
```

[image: The rendered HTML file where the second chunk produces an error]

So apparently `glue` trips over the environments when used within `purrr::map`.

How would I call `render` with an own environment without generating this error? Ideally, I do not want to chnage the `Rmarkdown` itself.

### Update

Interestingly enough, if I wrap `glue` in an own `function` things work smoothly again:

````
```
glue <- function(...) glue::glue(...)
map_chr(x, glue)
```
````

### Update 2

The problem seems not to be related to `knitr/rmarkdown`, but is a general scoping issue which seems to have to do with the environments the involved functions are defined:

```r
library(rlang)
library(purrr)
library(glue)
rm(list = ls())

e <- env(a = 1, x = "`a` has the value: {a}")
delayedAssign("res", map_chr(x, glue), e, e)
e$res
# Error:
# ℹ In index: 1.
# Caused by error:
# ! object 'a' not found

## as opposed to

a <- 1
x <- "`a` has the value: {a}"
delayedAssign("res", {
   map_chr(x, glue)
})
res

# [1] "`a` has the value: 1"
```

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this issue with ‘knitr’ instead of ‘rmarkdown’? And maybe even without either? If so, that's almost certainly a weird bug in ‘glue’.

Comment: Good question, my assumption is it is a general scoping related to the environments in which the variables and funcitons are defined. see my update dpost.

Comment: This would make the variable `a` available in the new environment, and the rmarkdown code would work as expected.

ne <- new.env();

assign("a",1, envir = ne);

render("env.Rmd", envir = ne);
`

Comment: @arman Nope: same error as before. And even if it worked, it would be rather cumbersome (and practically impossible) to define all variables from within an `Rmarkdown` externally again.

Comment: I think you've solved it although you don't need to alias the glue function, you can instead use a lambda/anonymous function in your `map()` call:  `map_chr(x, \(v) glue(v))`.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento It's a workaround for sure, but not really not a satisfactory long-term solution. This is a bug in ‘glue’ and should be fixed there.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - yes I agree, `solved` was a poor choice of words.  A bug report should indeed be submitted.

Comment: Bug report submitted: https://github.com/tidyverse/glue/issues/287

Comment: @RitchieSacramento I wanted to ping you to point you to the answer I now submitted, which explains why I was wrong before, and *this is not a bug*.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - thank you for that.  Makes sense now that you've clearly explained it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with either RMarkdown or ‘glue’. It’s also not a bug, contrary to what I claimed previously. In fact, the issue can be reproduced by simply accessing a variable inside the environment `e`, e.g. via the `get` function:

```
e = env(a = 1)
local(lapply("a", get), envir = e)
# Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'a' not found
```

This is a consequence of R’s [lexical scoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29#Lexical_scope) rules:

`lapply` executes `FUN` (= `get`) inside its call frame.<sup>1</sup> Due to the way R scoping works,<sup>2</sup> `FUN` will look up variable names in its calling scope. This calling scope is the `lapply` call frame. Of course `a` does not exist in the call frame of `FUN` (by contrast, `X` and `FUN` exist, since they are parameter names of `lapply`).

If R does not find a name in the local scope, it continues searching “upwards”, in the parent environment of the current environment. The parent environment of a call frame is the environment in which the function was *defined*. In the case of `lapply`, this is `namespace:base`.

`namespace:base` *also* does not define the name `a`, so the search continues upwards. Its parent environment is `.GlobalEnv`.<sup>3</sup> And that is why `lapply("a", get)` *works* (purely by accident!) if we defined `a` inside the global environment.<sup>4</sup> However, in our case where we defined `a` inside another environment, that environment *is never searched*, unless we `attach()` it to the search path (but of course that’s a bad idea).

The workaround is to invoke the function (either `glue` or `get`, or whatever needs to access local variables) inside an anonymous function. Strictly speaking **we should *always* do this, not just when working on a different environment**:

```
local(lapply("a", \(.) get(.)), envir = e)
# [1] "1.000000"
```

This works because the anonymous function `\(.) get(.)` is defined inside the calling scope which, in this example, is `e`. So when `lapply` executes this function, `get` first searches the name `a` in the local scope of the anonymous function, doesn’t find `a`, and then walks up the chain of parent environments. And the first parent environment is the environment in which the anonymous function was defined: `e`.

Note, however, that we need to take care with the choice of our parameter name! Because the scope of the anonymous function is the first one that is searched, it takes precedence and can hide our intended variable:

```
# Works:
local(lapply("a", \(.) get(.)), envir = e)
# [[1]]
# [1] 1

# Fails:
local(lapply("a", \(a) get(a)), envir = e)
# [[1]]
# [1] "a"
```

---

<sup>1</sup> In fact `lapply` is implemented as an internal function in C; but for the sake of this discussion we can pretend that it is defined in R as follows:

```r
lapply = function (X, FUN, ...) {
  FUN = match.fun(FUN)
  if (! is.vector(X) || is.object(X)) X = as.list(X)
  res = vector('list', length(X))

  for (i in seq_along(X)) res[[i]] = FUN(X[[i]], ...)
  res
}
```

Also note that I am using `lapply` instead of `map_chr`, but analogous reasoning applies to `map_chr`.

<sup>2</sup> I would like to emphasise that R’s scoping rules make perfect sense and are internally consistent, even though it is inconvenient in this case. In fact, lexical scoping is generally *superior* to other scoping rules.

<sup>3</sup> I’ve argued before that this is in fact a *bug in R*. At the very least it is a seriously questionable design decision which leads to errors and misunderstandings, and this question is a prime example. For this reason, [my package ‘box’](https://klmr.me/box/) defines module environments differently, [specifically to avoid this behaviour](https://github.com/klmr/box/discussions/274#discussioncomment-2723942).

<sup>4</sup> For example (and to illustrate that the original code really only worked *purely by accident!*), consider the following, where we change the variable name `a` to `sum`:

```
sum = 1
lapply("sum", get)
# [[1]]
# function (..., na.rm = FALSE)  .Primitive("sum")
```

… oops! `get` didn’t return the value of the global variable we defined but rather a function defined in `namespace:base`, because `namespace:base` comes *before* `.GlobalEnv` in the chain of parent environments that get searched. And the same is true in the case of `purrr::map_chr`.